Black blur in threejs
I am rendering a scene in threejs.
Image
The image i am getting has black blurs .
I have added antialias and setPixelRatio but neither work
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)


Sharing just the renderer configuration is not sufficient for investigating the issue. It's best if you demonstrate the rendering artifacts with a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/cp7t8h94/

A live example would be best. It looks like you're drawing a city, so have your scene be a simple ground plane + a cube, and configure the camera the same you do in your own code. (Just a guess, this looks like either a toon shader issue, or z-fighting.)
